# Workflow If-else loop not sending notifications to a group address but sends to individual email address in a variable. I'm confused

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, loop

I have created a if-else loop in SharePoint Designer 2013 and added a variable named "SDG_Email"
For example, if value in the form of SDG is "SDG Connectivity"
Set Variable "SDG_Email" to value "SDGCONNECTIVITY@.....AC.UK"
then send email to "SDG_EMAIL"

But it doesn't send any emails.

Rather if I add one of the value of variable to (individual email): if value in the form of SDG is SDG Connectivity" Set Variable to "noman.rafique@.....AC.UK" and send email to "SDG_EMAIL"

It works.

So the scenario is I have different SDG's and I want the variable to send the notifications to the group (which is not working) rather than individual person " which is working"

I am not understanding this because on the server it doesn't tried even to send an email to "SDGCONNECTIVITY@....AC.UK".

Comment: Sharepoint can only send mail to internal adresses, any mailadress outside of the sire collection user list is considered external. You need to add the actual group to the site collection (so it get’s added to the hidden user list) and then it should work.

Comment: Hi Christoffer, thanks for the info. Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I mean how can I add the actual group to the site collection?

Comment: By granting permission to the group, you can then remove the permission after a while, as it will remain in the hidden user list.

Comment: So give the group read permissions and then try again.

Comment: For some reason if I go to the Site settings -> site permissions -> and try to give permissions this group is not coming in there.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much bro

Comment: Added it as an answer + some details.

Comment: Great . Marked as well. Thank you

Comment: Can you upvote my post as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint can only send mail to internal addresses, any mail-address outside of the site collections hidden user list is considered external.

You need to add the actual group to the site collection (so it get’s added to the hidden user list) either by granting the group access to the site (read) is enough, and then check the hidden user list to make sure that the account/group were added. This takes a few moments.

To check the list, append this to the sitecollection URL.

```
/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

Another thing to "add" users or group to the hidden user list is to actually add them in a people picker field. This will add them to the list as well (without granting permissions to said user/group).

More information about the hidden user list: [SharePoint's hidden user-list - User Information List](https://zimmergren.net/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list/)